# How can I set values in a list from rows (input field) that are added or deleted dynamically?

Tags: lightning-web-components, dynamic, inputfield

First I have one row. On 'and' button I added two more. I want to get a list of values from input fields. How can I do this?

from .html file

```
 <template for:each={itemList} for:item="item" for:index="index">
                    <div key={item.id}>
                    <div class="slds-grid">
                    <div class="slds-col">
                            <b><lightning-input name="valueFilter"  onchange={valueFilter_onchange}></lightning-input></b>
                        </div>
                        <div class="slds-p-top_medium">
                            <lightning-button-icon icon-name="utility:delete" access-key={item.id} id={index}
                            alternative-text="Delete Row" title="Delete Row" onclick={removeRow} variant="bare " size="medium">
                        </lightning-button-icon>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                        <lightning-button-group>
                        <b><lightning-button  label="And" title="Add Row" onclick={addRow}
                        access-key={item.id} id={index} ></lightning-button></b>

                        </lightning-button-group>
                    </div>
            </template>
```

from .js file

```
 keyIndex = 0;
    @track itemList = [
        {
            id: 0,
        }
    ];
    addRow() {
      ++this.keyIndex;
      var newItem = [{ id: this.keyIndex}];
      this.itemList = this.itemList.concat(newItem);
      this.disableButtonOR = true;
  }
 
    removeRow(event) {
        if (this.itemList.length >= 2) {

            this.itemList = this.itemList.filter(function (element) {
                return parseInt(element.id) !== parseInt(event.target.accessKey);
            });
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are handling the finish event from handleFinish()

```js
    handleFinish( event ) {
        //the next line will return all lighting inputs from the screen, if you want to access their value I do recommend creating a loop and using .value
        let lstUserInput = [... this.template.querySelectorAll('lightning-input')];
        console.log(JSON.stringify(lstUserInput));
        let lstValues = lstUserInput.map( element => { return element.value });
        console.log(lstValues);
    }
```

Here the demo for it: https://app.lwc.studio/edit/9HVcKiGdV6kRgHIAZqB4/src/app.js?p=stories

Comment: I get this from console.log.
"[{\"$$ShadowedNodeKey$$\":130,\"$$HostElementKey$$\":66},{\"$$ShadowedNodeKey$$\":134,\"$$HostElementKey$$\":66},{\"$$ShadowedNodeKey$$\":146,\"$$HostElementKey$$\":66},{\"$$ShadowedNodeKey$$\":170,\"$$HostElementKey$$\":66},{\"$$ShadowedNodeKey$$\":192,\"$$HostElementKey$$\":66}]"

Comment: Do you have more lighting inputs on the code?

Comment: Yes, I have three. Two of them are lightning-combobox.

Comment: both console.logs are returning those values?

Comment: why are you using @track still?
also which version is in the .xml?

Comment: Are you testing directly on salesforce or in another place? It should work on Salesforce with no problems

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140638/discussion-between-maria-and-elivelton-walter).